Did the Quran copy this Syriac legend?
Can anyone make an argument that the Quran did not copy from the Alexander Syriac legend. For the similarities refer to reddit
Despite the many major parallels between the 2 stories, we also see minor similarities such as this.

"the Qurʾānic narrative specifically elaborates on the Alexander story in the Syriac work is confirmed by an important detail that has escaped the attention of previous scholars, namely, the material composition of the gate erected by the two protagonists, Alexander and Ḏū-l-Qarnayn, in the Syriac and Arabic texts, respectively. Like Alexander in the Syriac work, Ḏū-l-Qarnayn constructs his barrier from iron and bronze components. This coincidence is significant, since all references to the motif of Alexander’s (non-apocalyptic) gates in sources earlier than the Neṣḥānā mention only iron as the metal from which the barrier was made. This literary development is not coincidental and relates to the broader apocalyptic and political ideology expressed by the Syriac author in his work. The introduction of bronze as an additional material in the narrative reflects the author’s intention to evoke Danielic imagery on the succession of the world kingdoms, with the ultimate goal of strengthening his reading about the special role that the Greco-Roman Empire would play in sacred history. These ideological nuances are not reflected in the Qurʾānic account, which nonetheless preserves the literary transformation of Alexander’s iron gates into an apocalyptic barrier composed from the melting of iron and bronze"

Most secular historians identify dhul qarnayn as Alexander, can anyone argue the case for Quranic priority even though other stories from Christian Syriac texts have made it into the Quran(also as a side question I would like to know whether the dating of the infancy gospels is valid)
How do we reconcile Alexander being recognised dhul qarnayn .could we claim that the legend was around for a while and was later falsely attributed to Alexander? Or that the dating of these texts is incorrect


Please revise the title to ask a question. 2. [help] discourages questions of the form "I think x amirite"?  3. Please cite quotations so that we aren't accused of plagiarism. 3. What is the legend? What is it you want us to research and answer?


Despite reading this several times, I'm not entirely sure what is being asked.  If the fundamental question is "(I would like to know whether the dating of the infancy gospels is valid)", then the question would have to address how the infancy gospels were dated.

The main question is wether the quran copied the story or that both the Alexander Syriac legend and the quran could have come about through independent sources

Here's a source that seems to clearly establish that the Quran story comes from the Syriac: http://islam-and-muslims.com/Quran-Historical-Context.pdf#page=193

@Tahir, please edit the question to make it clear; if people have to read the comments to understand the question, they'll skip the question.

Whatever the details, I suggest 'For the similarities refer to reddit' is wholly unreasonable.
Other views are welcome and mine is that at worst, you take the trouble to summarise your own argument…

@RobbieGoodwin I apologise for the bad wording , all I wanted to do was refer the post for further inquiry if necessary , i have certainly expanded on the part of my question that was necessary

If 'I have certainly expanded on the part of my question that was necessary' actually worked in English, it would seem to suggests that I and everyone else here re-read everything you wrote, then somehow compared it to what was there before you expanded it…
Could you try something more realistic? Could you just Post a fresh Comment clearing everything up without requiring anyone else to do all that work?
While you're doing that, can you also provide chapter and verse references to specific passages in the Koran that deal with your idea?


Question:
Can anyone make an argument that the Quran did not copy from the Alexander Syriac legend.

Answer:
You overstate support among secular scholars a bit for the explanation for the similarities of the two texts.  It is a topic of debate with no clear definitive accepted solution.

On The Sources Of The Qur'anic Dhul-Qarnayn
Among Western scholars, the issue of Dhul-Qarnayn (the two-horned one) in Qur'an 18:82 had been a source of great debate. The debate surrounds not only the identity of Dhul-Qarnayn but also the sources of the Qur'anic story.

The Koran does not identify the prophetic dhul qarnayn as Alexander.  Alternative identities often cited are Cyrus the Great of Persia.  A messianic figure referred to in Christian and Jewish texts as having prophetic powers which neither religion attributed to Alexander.
Alternative explanations for the similarities include a common cultural oral tradition which is a source of both works.  For example the Epic of Gilgamesh describes a legendary Mesopotamian figure travelling to the end of the earth from 2000BC.  Gilgamesh's story is incomplete to modern scholarship but it is believed to be the basis of Hercules and many other oral traditions across the ancient world.
The communities (Persian, Byzantine, Arab, and Christian communities) were geographically proximal and highly influential on each other, so this also fits whether Gilgamesh or some as of yet unknown basis.
Islamic scholars argue that for them the Koran is a revelation from God, thus any similarities between previous historical works could be God's reaffirmation of the correctness of these previous works rather than a reflection of direct influence from the previous written work on the newer religious text.
The question of whether the Quran "copied" the Syriac Alexander Romance remains open to interpretation, but the evidence suggests a more nuanced understanding is needed. The Quranic narrative of Dhul-Qarnayn and the Syriac Alexander legend share notable parallels, particularly in their depiction of a world-conquering figure who builds a barrier to protect against Gog and Magog. However, whether these parallels are the result of direct borrowing, indirect influence, or a shared cultural tradition is a matter of scholarly debate.

This is an excellent answer

The parallels about the wall (also the contents of the wall) and travel of the 2 persons around the world along with the murky waters make the connection almost undeniable , the pdf attached in the comment on the post also elaborated on this

@Tahir,  the similarities in the text are not in dispute.  The question was to explain other plausible explanations scholars debate which could explain those similarities beyond copying from the older text to the newer text.

There is no unanimous opinion among scholars that Dul Karnayn was Alexander the Great. Some say it was Cyrus the Great, other also say that it was Darius the Great.
